# Create android eclipse project using SRC and res folder

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

**Sir**
I have a project having only src and res folder
And I know that it is targets api 22 
And it need library Google play service and v7 compat .
How do I create a project in eclipse or Android studio having above things please help?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Did you read any documentation?

Comment: No sir. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this for everything you need to know: http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

**EDIT:**

In Android Studio, look in the toolbar for File->New->New Project. Android Studio will guide you through the process and you can specify your target API and things from there on.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not develop the ADT plugin(the required plugin so you can develop android in eclipse) and they recomend you transfer to Android studio. I have had that same problem with appcompat crap and it is solvable in two ways(as far as I have seen):

1: Use Android Studio instead, as it really truly supports all android related dev requirements, including app compat.

2: In your project, set minimum API level to Android 4.0.3 or above. This way you prevent the requirement for appcompat.

I recently transfered from Eclipse to Android Studio, and the transition was easy, and once I found out how I could use the Eclipse keybindings, it was just the GUI that was different. It is really easy geting used to Android Studio, and I recomend you start using it as soon as you can. It will solve most of your problems related to appcompat and other libraries that needs to be added to support earlier versions of Android

[image]

As you see on the image, there is a "Minumum required SDK". The minimum SDK and target SDK are two different options, and target should be the newest SDK, while minimum should be(in my opinion) Android 4.0.3 or higher. According to Google, this allows you to reach about 90% of all Android users

**EDIT**

Using Android Studio, as long as the SDK has everything installed and Android Studio is as new as possible, it will add appcompat v7 automatically without issues. Eclipse's ADT plugin is outdated and probably doesn't support appcompat anymore. I personally preffer eclipse, but due to android issues, I had to move over to Android Studio